# Google Apps Script call Address Validation API

Tags: google-apps-script, postman, google-address-validation-api

Simple code and straightforward. It works with postman but fails with Apps Script.

```
function validateAddress () {

  const url = 'https://addressvalidation.googleapis.com/v1:validateAddress?key=';
  const apikey = '...';

  let payload, options, temp;

  payload = JSON.stringify({
    "address": {
      "addressLines": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy"
    }
  });

  options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'body': payload
  }

  temp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + apikey, options);
  Logger.log(temp)

}
```

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Address is missing from request.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Change `options` to

```
  options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'payload': payload
  }
```

Gives error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"address\":{\"addressLines\":\"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\"}}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"address\":{\"addressLines\":\"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\"}}' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"address\":{\"addressLines\":\"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\"}}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"address\":{\"addressLines\":\"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\"}}' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/requests-validate-address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/validateAddress#PostalAddress), it seems that `addressLines` is an array of string, not a string. Does that change something ? (I don't have a key, so I cannot try myself).

And more important, your `options` object is incorrect (check [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))). It should be

```
options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'POST',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': payload
  }
```

Comment: addressLines works on postman with array or string. "payload" gives different error.

Comment: please show the new error then

Comment: I don't know why it works with Postman but still, try to declare an array for addressLines, it might be the issue

Comment: Changed `addressLines ` to array, error are the same (exactly the same).

Comment: have you well written contentType and not Content-Type in the `options` ? You sure you're not stringify the JSON twice ?

Comment: Aahhh... fool me, I knew it must be a stupid mistake. Changing `Content-Type ` to `contentType` actually solves the problem too. It's all clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it works but changed `options` to

```
  options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    'payload': payload
  }
```

Solves the problem.

Comment: in the headers you can write `Content-Type`, in the object `options`(first level of properties) you can have `contentType`. But you can't put one for the other.